# Sort list by multiple fields(not then compare) in java

Tags: java, sorting

Now I have an object:

```
public class Room{
    private long roomId;
    private long roomGroupId;
    private String roomName;
    ... getter 
    ... setter
}
```

I want sort list of rooms by 'roomId', but in the meantime while room objects has 'roomGroupId' greator than zero and has same value then make them close to each other.
Let me give you some example:

input:

```
[{"roomId":3,"roomGroupId":0},
 {"roomId":6,"roomGroupId":0},
 {"roomId":1,"roomGroupId":1},
 {"roomId":2,"roomGroupId":0},
 {"roomId":4,"roomGroupId":1}]
```

output:

```
[{"roomId":6,"roomGroupId":0},
 {"roomId":4,"roomGroupId":1},
 {"roomId":1,"roomGroupId":1},
 {"roomId":3,"roomGroupId":0},
 {"roomId":2,"roomGroupId":0}]
```

As shown above, the list sort by 'roomId',  but 'roomId 4' and 'roomId 1' are close together, because they has the same roomGroupId.

Comment: It's an interesting problem! What happens if your input be `(3,0),(6,0),(1,1),(2,0),(4,1),(4,2),(2,2)`?? What is the final order?

Comment: My guess is that room ID should be unique.

Comment: @majidhajibaba I think 'roomId' is the PK, so number-2 should not twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not have easy nice solution (maybe I am wrong).

You can do this like this

```
        TreeMap<Long, List<Room>> roomMap = new TreeMap<>();

        rooms.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Room::getRoomGroupId))
             .forEach((key, value) -> {
                 if (key.equals(0L)) {
                     value.forEach(room -> roomMap.put(room.getRoomId(), Arrays.asList(room)));
                 } else {
                     roomMap.put(
                         Collections.max(value, Comparator.comparing(Room::getRoomId))
                                    .getRoomId(),
                         value
                             .stream()
                             .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Room::getRoomId)
                                               .reversed())
                             .collect(Collectors.toList())
                     );
                 }
             });

        List<Room> result = roomMap.descendingMap()
                                   .entrySet()
                                   .stream()
                                   .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue()
                                                          .stream())
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're in Java 8, you can use code like this

```
Collections.sort(roomList, Comparator.comparing(Room::getRoomGroupId)
            .thenComparing(Room::getRoomId));
```

If not, you should use a comparator

```
class SortRoom implements Comparator<Room> 
{ 
 
    public int compare(Room a, Room b) 
    { 
        if (a.getRoomGroupId().compareTo(b.getRoomGroupId()) == 0) {
            return a.getRoomId().compareTo(b.getRoomId());
        }
            
        return a.getRoomGroupId().compareTo(b.getRoomGroupId(); 
    } 
}
```

and then use it like this

```
Collections.sort(roomList, new SortRoom());
```

Comment: This will not produce the desired output. This will place all the zero group ids first, than all the 1.. etc..